# My listview doest'n scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I want to display a list of items when I click a **Save** button, but they don't scroll. 
 [image]
[image]

`ListView` doesn't scroll on this screen.

Comment: Are you using ListView inside ScrollView.. if you do so then remove scorllview

Comment: yes.i am using scroll view first top of layout @JaiSoni

Comment: if You use listview inside scroll like <ScrollView><Listview></Listview></ScrollView> then your list view will not scroll

Comment: not i am user <ScrollView> into inflator ..can i scroll listview and anohter scroll should be disable @JaiSoni

Answer (score 2):

you can use this method to put your ListView in a ScrollView:

```
private void setListViewScrollable(final ListView list) {
        list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                listViewTouchAction = event.getAction();
                if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    list.scrollBy(0, -1);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                    int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    list.scrollBy(0, 1);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

in Activity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//...
setListViewScrollable(myListView);
}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: hifriends thanks to response i get solution do u elobrtar list.scrollBy(0, 1); @breceivemail

Comment: @altaf please select it as answer

Answer (score 0):

```
lisview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```